# Can one use hyperledger-composer client-API from within Angular App?

Tags: angular, hyperledger-composer, dynamic-queries

I would like to use dynamic queries from within the angular-code of my hyperledger-composer app:

That is, instead of within a transaction processor function, I want to write something like the following within my angular-app:

```
const connection = new BusinessNetworkConnection();
await connection.connect('admin@network-name');
const query = connection.buildQuery('SELECT org.example.SampleAsset WHERE (value == _$inputValue)');
const assets = await connection.query(query, { inputValue: 'blue' })
```

Is this possible? What library would I have to import in order to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

So you are looking for a way to integrate your Angular Appp with an composer Business Network, right?

The easiest way to do this is via composer-rest-server.
This creates a web-server which servers as a gateway for all communication between client and business network.
See here: https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/integrating/getting-started-rest-api

But it is also possible to achieve direct communication between client and business network. This would basically be done in the same way you would write tests for the business network. 
See here for an example: 
https://github.com/IBM/Decentralized-Energy-Composer/blob/master/test/test.js